# how to differentiate between on notification click and on notification button click

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

when I'm clicking the notification it self and the action button it does the same, I want to differentiate between them, I want the button do something and when I click the notification is self something else, here is my code-

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.notificationticker))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notificationtitle))
            .setContentText(yeah)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_favorite, getString(R.string.azor), pIntent)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass different PendingIntents to `addAction` and `setContentIntent`.
Currently they both use the same *pIntent* instance.

If you want them both to launch the same activity but do something different, you can add extra's to the Intent used to make the pending intent.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do two things.

1. On click of notification, it should resume the paused activity.
2. On click of notification action button, it should execute some code.

So, I have created two pending intents. One is for notification click event and another is for action button click.

```
Intent hangup_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialerScren.class)
            .putExtra("intent_action", "hangup");
    hangup_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent hangup_pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1, hangup_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent click_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialerScren.class)
            .putExtra("intent_action", "click");
    click_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent click_pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 2, click_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Action hangupAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_call_end_24,
            "Hangup", hangup_pending);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channelId);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentTitle("Title");
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);
    builder.setContentText("sample_text");
    builder.setContentIntent(click_pending);
    builder.setDeleteIntent(click_pending);
    builder.addAction(hangupAction);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
```

In this way I did. To execute on notification click and notification action button click.

And other side at the activity onNewIntent() method, check for passed value from the pending intent, is that click OR hangup

```
String action = null;
    try {
        if (intent != null) {
            action = intent.getExtras().getString("intent_action");
        } else {
            action = "UnSpecified";
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    try{
        if(action.equals("hangup")){
            //code for hangup notification action button clicked
        }else if(action.equals("click")){
           //code for notification clicked
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```